# Head is being assigned to Null each time when the insert_node() function is calling in the linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

Please Review the following code snippet. I am trying to insert elements into linked list using the double pointer concept.

Problem is: Every time the 'Head' element is being assigned to 'NULL' which is not desirable except for the first insertion. please give the Suggestions to resolve this problem.

```
class Node{
      public:
      int item;
      Node *next;
      Node(){};
   };  

   class List{
     public:
     Node *head;
     Node **lpp1;
     Node *lp1;
     Node *newnode;
     List(){head=NULL;};
     void insert_node(Node*,Node**,Node*);
     void delete_node(int,Node*,Node*);
    .
    .
    .
    .   
    .
    };   

  void List::insert_node(Node* newlp,Node **lpp,Node *lp)
     {
       *lpp=head;
       cout<<"\n value of the *lpp points to :"<<*lpp;
       cout<<"\n Initial Address of the head is:"<<head;`

       if((*lpp)!=NULL)
        {
     for(lpp=&head;(*lpp)!=NULL;lpp=&(*lpp)->next){
       lp=*lpp;
           if(newlp->item<lp->item){
        newlp->next=lp;
        *lpp=newlp;
        break;
        }
       else{
         lp->next=newlp;
              *lpp=lp;
              break;
        }

        }   

    }

    else{
      head=newnode;
      cout<<"\n address of head is  :"<<head;
      cout<<"\n "<<head->item<<" is head.";
    }

     }

 int main()
  {
   List l;
   l.insert_node(l.newnode,l.lpp1,l.lp1);
  }
```

the output I am getting is :

```
1st insertion:

Enter the element to be inserted:34

value of the *lpp points to : 0 
Initial Address of the head is: 0
address of the head is :0x8dd2008
 34 is head.
2nd Insertion:

Enter the element to be inserted:56

value of the *lpp points to : 0 
Initial Address of the head is: 0 
address of the head is :0x8dd2018 
56 is head.
```

Comment: can Any one please help me in knowing this issue. this was coded in C++

Comment: Your posted code and output don't match. It's hard to see where the problem might be.

Comment: Hi sahu, The lines 1st insertion and 2nd insertion in the above output shown were added for the purpose of readability only. You can Ignore those lines and consider remaining output for better understanding. Mainly the problem with the 'head' element is re-assigning with null each time insert_node() function is calling.

Comment: There is nothing in your posted code that shows how you get the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment "*lpp=head;" is incorrect because "lpp" is null, and "*lpp" attempts to dereference a null (or uninitialized) pointer. Make sure that whenever you dereference a pointer, that pointer is not null.

The
    Node **lpp1;
    Node *lp1;
    Node *newnode;
members are not initialized. You don't actually even need those members. All you need in class List is the pointer to the head node.

Comment: Thank you Very much Oleg for your Valuable Answer,